# Elastic Search: Any way to make space-separated words in a comma-separated list regarded as one term?

Tags: match, elasticsearch

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm trying to search by locations with an "exact search" option. There are a couple fields that get searched, with the most important one being the "location_raw" field:

```
"match": {
    "location.location_raw": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "operator": "AND",
        "query": "[location query]",
        "analyzer": "standard"
     }
}
```

The location_raw field is a location string with a comma between each place, such as "Sudbury, Middlesex, Massachusetts" or "Leamington, Warwickshire, England". If someone searches for "Sudbury, Middlesex" it gets passed in as

```
"query": "Sudbury Middlesex"
```

and both of those terms must exist in the location_raw field. This part works.

The problem is that when the location_raw field contains multi-word location, like New York or Saint George, these get returned when someone searches for "York" or "George." If I do an exact search for "George," I do not want to get results for "Saint George." Is there any way to make Elastic consider "Saint George" one term in the string "Saint George, Stamford, Lincoln, England"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, but you have to query in csv too, or use a [terms filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_execution_mode).

I used a [pattern analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) with a simple pattern: `", "`. I set up a simple index with a single document:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "csv": {
               "type": "pattern",
               "pattern": ", ",
               "lowercase": false
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "location": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "csv",
               "search_analyzer": "standard",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"location":"Saint George, Stamford, Lincoln, England"}
```

I can see the terms generated with a simple [terms aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html):

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "location_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "location"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "location_terms": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "England",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Lincoln",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Saint George",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Stamford",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And then if I query with the same csv syntax, the document isn't returned for "George, England":

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "location": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "operator": "AND",
            "query": "George, England",
            "analyzer": "csv"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 0,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

but is for "Saint George, England":

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "location": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "operator": "AND",
            "query": "Saint George, England",
            "analyzer": "csv"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.2169777,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2169777,
            "_source": {
               "location": "Saint George, Stamford, Lincoln, England"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This query is equivalent, and probably more performant:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "location": [
                  "Saint George",
                  "England"
               ],
               "execution": "and"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/234ea93accb7b20ad8fd33e62fe92f1d450a51ab